# Spring Actuator conflicting with Springfox: 'documentationPluginsBootstrapper' exception

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, swagger, springfox

I have upgraded my Spring Boot project to 2.7.4 & Springfox to 3.0.0.
But this resulted in the exception,

> **Failed to start bean 'documentationPluginsBootstrapper'; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException**

After doing some research, I added the following config in the `application.properties`, but the issue was still not fixed.

```
spring.mvc.pathmatch.matching-strategy=ant-path-matcher
```

Then I found out that, **Spring Actuator** is causing this issue, and setting the following property fixed the issue.

```
management.server.port=8082
```

I don't want to define a custom management port, instead I want it to take the default server port.

Why is Actuator conflicting with Springfox? How do I fix this issue?

**pom.xml**

```
<parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.4</version>
        <relativePath />
</parent>

<properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <spring.cloud-version>2021.0.4</spring.cloud-version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
        <artifactId>springfox-boot-starter</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

**Springfox Swagger Config**

```
@Configuration
@EnableSwagger2
public class SwaggerConfig {

    @Bean
    public Docket productApi() {
        return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2).select()
                .apis(RequestHandlerSelectors.basePackage("com.swagger.io")).paths(PathSelectors.any()).build();
    }
}
```

Comment: I added the same issue and I sorted it by adding: management.server.port=8082

Answer (score 1):

Springfox has not been maintained for quite some time now. Getting it to work with Spring Boot 2.7 is possible by disabling more recent Spring Boot features but probably not worth your time. It's unlikely to work at all with Spring Boot 3.

You can use Springdoc instead. The migration is usually not much work: https://springdoc.org/migrating-from-springfox.html

Answer (score 0):

this also work for me  by using the below property at my bootstrap.properties
management.server.port=0

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).